# Can we define log-convex operators?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, convexity, operator-theory

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$. A function $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, is said to be *log-convex* if $\log f$ is convex or equivalently for all $x,y\in I$ and $\alpha\in [0,1]$
$$f(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\leq [f(x)]^\alpha [f(y)]^{1-\alpha}.$$
Let $X$ be a vector lattice algebra and $F:X\rightarrow X$. Can we define the log-convexity of $F$ in a similar way? If yes, can someone give me a reference to such definition?

Comment: What would the exact statement be? $\|F(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\|\leq\|F(x)\|^\alpha\|F(y)\|^{1-\alpha}$? This means that $N\circ F:X\to[0,\infty)$ is log-convex, where $N(x)=\|x\|$, so it reduces to log-convexity of real valued functions. If you mean something else, what kind of order and powers do you have in mind?

Comment: It should be $$F(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y)\leq [F(x)]^\alpha [F(y)]^{(1-\alpha)},\quad x,y\in X$$

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to state, because the usual structure of a normed space does not allow taking powers and comparing elements. For $z\in X$, what does $z^\alpha$ mean? If $z,w\in X$, what do $zw$ and $z\leq w$ mean? It would help if you could elaborate on the meaning of your statement.

Comment: It would definitely make sense if I replace the normed space with $\textbf{Vector Lattice Algebra}$.

Comment: Thank you prof. Joonas Ilmavirta for correction. I have edited the question too.

Comment: For starters, if you restrict to positive elements in your space, then this should be doable. Probably best to think in terms of convex cones with the associated partial order.

Comment: @Suvrit Thank you. Is there such developed theory? I mean if you can provide me a reference?

Comment: One introduction to this for positive definite matrices (as a classical example) is to look at my paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1039  (the citations in that paper will lead you to more classical references for related material)